26x2.10/2.25 inner tube in 26x1.95 tire
I replaced the tires on my MTB. The new tires have dimension 26x1.95. The markings on the inner tubes (which I am re-using) says 26x2.10/2.25. It seems like it did fit just well, but am I running at risk? Thanks

Guess the biggest problem woild be pinching them while fitting in the tubes, but could pinch them while riding too ??? Time will tell, let us know

I chickened out and bought inner tubes from the same manufacturer, specifically for the tire spec.

In general you can use tubes that are slightly too big, or slightly too small, with little to no risk. With tubes that are designated for sizes larger than your current tire the key concern is that you can fit the tube inside and inflate it without there being wrinkles, folds, or pinch points which will cause flats.
See Is my inner tube to big? here on this site for more details.
